# git global config for showing untracked files

Tags: git, configuration

Why does this work:

`git config status.showuntrackedfiles no`

but not this:

`git config --global status.showuntrackedfiles no`

I thought --global could be used for all config options. Am I wrong?

Comment: Your command seems OK to me, does it say anything when it fails?

Comment: There is no error message. It seems to work except that tracked files appears when I run `git status` after setting `git config --global status.showuntrackedfiles no`

Comment: @IssamT. what is the output of `git config --list` in the repository?

Comment: @MykhailoKovalskyi if I use the first command (without global) then `git config --list` shows `status.showuntrackedfiles=no` twice among other lines. But if I use the second command (with global) it shows `status.showuntrackedfiles=no` and after some other lines it shows `status.showuntrackedfiles=normal`

Comment: After deleting `status.showuntrackedfiles=normal` from .git/config now the second command work fine as i switch the global config from no to normal and vis-versa.

Comment: Thank you @MykhailoKovalskyi. Since the list containted two options with the second one being the local, I guess the local option was overriding the global one. One way to fix it without messing with .git/config is `git config --unset status.showuntrackedfiles`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git config --list` shows `status.showuntrackedfiles=XXX` twice.

Since the list containted two options with the second one being the local, the local option was overriding the global one. One way to fix it is `git config --unset status.showuntrackedfiles`

After this only one instance of this option will be on the list (the global one), and its effect will take place as expected.

Comment: For those who, like I was, are wondering why some untracked files _still_ aren't listed - you might want to check your `.gitignore` file.